# What is the relative interior of this set?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, optimization, metric-spaces

Consider the set of points $S = \{(\cos(t), \sin(t))\; |\; 0\leq t \leq  \pi/2\}$  (an arc describing a quarter circle)

Is it true  that the ***relative interior*** of $S$ consists  of all points of the arc except the end points, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ ?

I am trying to show that by the definition
$\mathrm{relint}(S) := \{x \in S\;| \; \exists \;\delta > 0, B_\delta(x) \cap \mathrm{aff}(S) \subseteq S\}$ where $\mathrm{aff}(S)$ denotes the ***affine hull*** of $S$.

I am stuck because  $\mathrm{aff}(S)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence for any $x \in S$, $\delta >0, B_\delta(x) \cap \mathrm{aff}(S) = B_\delta(x)$ which is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence  never a subset of $S$. Thus I get  $\mathrm{relint}(S) = \{ \}$.

Comment: See here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144750/whats-the-difference-between-interior-and-relative-interior

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Do you think OP misunderstands the definition of relative interior? They have given a correct proof that the relative interior of $S$ is empty. If I'm not mistaken, I think the key point for OP is just to know that their argument is correct, and that the thing they had set out to prove is indeed false.

Answer (score 1):

The relative interior of $S$ is empty, for the reason you said.

Comment: In another question, that explained what rel interior means, the answer says that the interior of a line segment in R^2 is empty, but the rel interior of the line will consist of all except the end points. My conclusion here seems to contradict that answer.

Comment: @me10240 Note that the affine hull of a line segment is a line, not all of $\mathbb R^2$. There is no contradiction.

Comment: What's the reason for the delete vote? If there's an error in what I wrote, I'd like to know.

Comment: That quarter circle can be equivalently written as $\{x| x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1, x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0\}$. The affine hull is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that the relative interior of this arc is still with respect to the 2D balls, so it is empty. Is this correct?